# What do greyed out servers mean?

Tags: dayz-2012

Recently, *DayZ* has become easier to use via the Six Launcher.

There are times when servers appear to be greyed out. At first, I thought this was due to a version mismatch. Unfortunately, this is not the case, as is evident by this picture:

[image]

Two servers with two differing Versions are greyed out. Several other servers with those exact same versions are not greyed out.

**What causes these servers to go grey?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The greyed out servers are cause by a version mismatch of the DayZ mod.

From your screenshot you can see that the latest version of DayZ is 1.7.2.4, while the greyed out servers are still on 1.7.2.3

The version listed in the column is the Arma 2 version.

Comment: Oh... Well now I feel silly. I was looking at the wrong version. =(